# Is there a PCI card with a MIDI port?

Tags: pci, audio-recording

Does anyone know of a PCI card that I could install in my desktop that would give me a MIDI port?

Would it need to be a full sound card, or could it just be a dumb object? The distinction I'm making is I think mostly a price related one.

Answer (score 2):

Conventional MIDI connector functionality has largely moved to USB. You can get an inexpensive  USB based MIDI interface ([example](http://www.m-audio.com/products/en_us/MIDISPORT1x1.html)). So far as I know, the main problems are [latency](http://www.soundonsound.com/sos/Oct02/articles/pcmusician1002.asp) (i.e. delays in the overall sound path).

You can get PCI based MIDI interfaces, ([example](http://www.m-audio.com/products/en_us/Audiophile2496.html))
[image]

Answer (score 1):

None will give you a MIDI port, as the XLR jack is too large to fit. What they have is a DA-15 joystick connector that splits out into MIDI In, MIDI Out, and MIDI Thru XLR plugs. You can usually find them starting at about $5, splitter cable not included.

> The IBM DA15 PC game connector has been modified to add a (usually MPU-401 compatible) MIDI interface, and this is often implemented in the game connectors on third-party sound cards, for example the Sound Blaster line from Creative Labs.

[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature#Game_controller_ports)